# Reset Auto Increment ID using web browser

Tags: php, mysql, reset

Is this possible to execute this mysql command:

```
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE application SET application.number = @count:= @count + 1;
```

on a web browser in PHP. I want to execute this automatically after deleting the data.

Comment: Even if it would be possible what is the rationale behind doing it?

Comment: If you are trying to delete data and reset autoincrement why not use `TRUNCATE`?